# ACF dynamic image field for user is not working on webpage

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF to show different dynamic values in the user dashboard. All the other fields are working fine. But when I want to show a dynamic image then it creates problem.
I am useing elementor pro. So I thing it is a problem with elementor pro and ACF. So I go for custom code.
At first I add a custom image field for a post, and use this code.

```
<?php
$image = get_field($post_image); 
$pic = $image['sizes']['large'];
?>

<p><?php echo $pic; ?></p>
<?php var_dump($image);?>
```

and this code is working fine. But when I try to show image of a user with a code. it just shows me image id, not image. all image ACF settings are same for both post and user image field.

there is two code:
one is:

```
<?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id);
$userimg = get_field("$realtor_image",$user);
if( $userimg ) {
    echo $userimg;
} else {
    echo 'empty';
}
?>
```

another is:

```
<?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id);
$userimg = $user->realtor_image; 
?>

<p><?php echo $user->realtor_image; ?></p>
<?php var_dump($userimg);?>
```

and in the screenshot, you will see those above the line and below the like.
Can anyone please help me?
Output ss:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QfQf.jpg

Here is my image field ss:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv9WD.jpg

I am trying to show the image that is different from user to user, like what ACF actually does, showing dynamic content. I can do it for posts, but not for logged-in users. It is showing me the image id rather than the actual image. I have changed Return Format, but not work.

Comment: Where did you define any variable `$realtor_image`? Is that perhaps supposed to be just `realtor_image` instead ...?

Comment: Hi @CBroe, Yes , that looks like, you give me kind of a correct answer. But it gives me the URL rather than the image. Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use get_field() with proper arguments.

try replacing this code

```
<?php
    
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$userimg = get_field("realtor_image",'user_'.$user_id );
if( $userimg ) {
    echo $userimg;
} else {
    echo 'empty';
}
?>
```

Reference:- https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/